# Analog of pop() function

Tags: c++, stack

I'm working on stack calculator. It takes two elements from stack, does an operation on them and puts the result back. Here is a part of my code where the error appeared:

```
    int num1;
        num1=st.pop();
        int res;
```

But I receive the following error: `[Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be`. I was offered to avoid the `pop()` function so would like to know whether there are analogs of `pop()`function. I can write it by myself but if there is a built-in solution it would be fine.

Comment: [`std::stack::pop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) returns `void`, hence, such type can't be assigned to variable. Did you mean `num1=st.top (); st.pop ();`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing variables with meaningful values. That is, change `int num1; num1 = st.top();` to `int num1 = st.top();`. (Okay, it **did** address the question, because it fixed it; <g>)

Comment: You could have solved this yourself by reading the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack). That's the first place to look when you get an error message that you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`top()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) function which returns the reference to the top element in the stack.

The usual way is to read the element using `top()` and then popping it off the stack using `pop()`.

[pop()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) just removes the top element from the stack. It does not return anything.